# What are the complete set of steps to fully build a Monotouch app bundle from the command line?

Tags: c#, msbuild, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, xbuild

I'd like to know what the complete set of steps is to build a MonoTouch C# app consisting of the main application assembly containing xib files and a set of library assemblies that also possibly contain xib files.

We're trying to automate these steps via a proper MSBuild script (which MonoTouch has yet to support) for various reasons which I won't go into, to focus on the question here.

So far, here's what I've come up with:

1) Compile each assembly using smcs, e.g.

```
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/smcs /noconfig 
"/out:/Users/bright/src/MonoTouchAppWithLib/AppLib/bin/Debug/AppLib.dll
"/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll"
"/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll"
"/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll"
"/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll"
/nologo /warn:4 /debug:+ /debug:full /optimize- /codepage:utf8 
"/define:DEBUG"
/t:library "/Users/bright/src/MonoTouchAppWithLib/AppLib/Class1.cs"
```

2) Compile interface definitions: run ibtool on each xib file in each assembly, e.g

```
/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool 
--errors --warnings --notices --output-format human-readable-text    
"/Users/bright/src/App/App/ViewController_iPhone.xib" 
--compile "/Users/bright/src/App/App/bin/Debug/App.app/ViewController_iPhone.nib"
--sdk "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/
SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk"
```

3) Compile to native code:

```
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch 
-sdkroot "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" 
-v --nomanifest --nosign -sim
"/Users/bright/src/App/App/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/App.app" 
-r "/Users/bright/src/App/AppLib/bin/Debug/AppLib.dll" 
-r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll" 
-r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll" 
-r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll" 
-r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll" 
-debug -profiling -nolink -sdk "5.0"
"/Users/bright/src/App/App/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/App.exe"
```

However, it isn't clear how to do the following (taken from MonoDevelop's build output window), and in what order:

1) Extract embedded content. MonoDevelop just outputs this:

```
Extracted HelloWorldScreen_iPhone.nib from MtLib.dll
Extracted HelloWorldScreen_iPad.nib from MtLib.dll
```

2) Update application manifest: There's no command line given in the MonoDevelop build output window.

3) Update debug configuration file: There's no command line given in the MonoDevelop build output window.

4) Update debug settings file: There's no command line given in the MonoDevelop build output window.

And other steps I haven't gotten do yet like app signing and resources.

Hopefully we can get enough information here to make a go of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run, from a terminal window or from within an MSBuild task, the `/Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool` tool that is supplied with MonoDevelop. E.g.

```
/Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool -v build -t:Build "-c:Debug|iPhoneSimulator" /path/to/your/app.csproj
```

That will build the MonoTouch application, including all your steps above and any future feature that will be added.

Comment: No, that is not what I asked. I need to *create* an MSBuild script that runs the actual steps. In other words, I need to have MonoDevelop work in the "experimental" msbuild/xbuild setting, which has never worked. This is part of a larger integration process with msbuild.

Comment: Just to make sure the above comment is clear: Monotouch uses .csproj files for normal development, but does not run it via msbuild/xbuild. Instead it just parses what it can and leaves the rest. The result is an unpredictable mess when one tries to extend the build process - the csproj is simply not honored. What we're trying to do is what Monotouch plans to do "sometime in the future" - a real MSBuild environment that can be part of a larger workflow.

Comment: That's *presently* the only **complete** set of steps that allow you to build *any* MonoTouch application outside the MonoDevelop IDE (on the command-line). The `mtouch` tool has some options (e.g. manifest and signing) that be be used outside MD (even if MD use it's own code) but that does not cover every steps that the MD addin does (some only happens if specific circumstances).

Comment: Can't you just create an MSBuild script that calls mdtool?

Comment: Combining responses, the best way to go seems to be: 1) The checked-in .csproj files that are invoked from the solution are "real" msbuild scripts and run in the "experimental" msbuild/xbuild mode. 2) Each of these dynamically generates a .csproj file that adheres to the mdtool limitations, and 3) then runs mdtool on the generated file. Roundabout, but can probably be made reliable. Will post on how this turns out. Accepting poupou's answer since that started this line of thinking. Thanks!