# using MonoTouch / Mono for Android with Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, xamarin.android

Currently I am doing my first steps with MonoTouch and would like to continue with Mono for Android soon.
So far I am using the MonoDevelop IDE, but this is lacking lots of the features I got used to when using Eclipse.

How difficult would it be to integrate MonoTouch / Mono for Android with Eclipse?

This would solve a lot of problems for me :)

Comment: Could you be more specific about the things that you miss the most? If you could file feature requests for MonoDevelop at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com that would be great.

Comment: there are lots of small things here and there...

- the monodevelop support for subversion is very strange and unlogical

Answer (score 1):

It's *likely* easy for Mono for Android which uses an `msbuild` system (tasks) as Mono provides a compatible tool, called `xbuild` but it **won't** be easy for MonoTouch.

MonoTouch provides a tool, `mtouch` that does **most** (but not all) of the work to build iOS applications. You can see how it's used if you look at the **Build Output** inside MonoDevelop (inside the Error List Pad).

There are a few steps that are done by MonoDevelop iPhone Addin. Some of them can also be done using `mtouch` - but not all of them (it also depends on your project).

The following questions talks about a similar subject (using `msbuild` to drive MonoTouch builds).

- [MonoTouch: custom msbuild task error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464009/monotouch-custom-msbuild-task-error)
- [What are the complete set of steps to fully build a Monotouch app bundle from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395607/what-are-the-complete-set-of-steps-to-fully-build-a-monotouch-app-bundle-from-th)

Answer (score 0):

There is a whole lot of logic for building MonoTouch apps inside of MonoDevelop such as Info.plist and Entitlements.plist merging, compiling of xibs, compressing of icons, signing of packages, creation of IPAs, etc.

It's on our TODO list to port the existing build functionality over to msbuild tasks but it isn't likely to happen anytime soon as we have a lot more important things to implement/fix first.